# Python equivalent to inequality join in SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas, t-sql

I recently started using python at work instead of SQL. I don't have access to any servers, nor will IT allow me to install a local instance of SQL SERVER EXPRESS. The datasets are too large to use Excel or Access.

I'm using my limited knowledge of python as a workaround. I've successfully analyzed other datasets, but this one presents a new challenge.
I have a very large dataset (25 mill+ rows) and I would like to perform the equivalent to this:
IN T-SQL:

```
    SELECT
     A.TransactionDate,
     B.StartDate,
     B.EndDate,
     B.RefValue
    FROM table1 AS A
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS B 
     ON A.TransactionDate BETWEEN B.StartDate AND B.EndDate
```

OR

```
ON A.Date1 >= B.StartDate AND A.Date <= B.EndDate
```

Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'TranDate': ['2018/01/05', '2018/02/07', '2018/03/24']
        ,'Loc': [4000, 5000, 4200]
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'StartDate': ['2018/01/01', '2018/02/01', '2018/03/01']
        ,'EndDate': ['2018/01/31','2018/02/28', '2018/03/30']
        ,'PP': ['01', '02', '03']
    }
)
```

Expected Dataframe:

```
dfR = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'TranDate': ['2018/01/05', '2018/02/07', '2018/03/24']
        ,'Loc': [4000, 5000, 4200]
        ,'PP': ['01', '02', '03']
    }
)
```

I tried using the `pandas.merge()` statement, but there is no option for an inequality.

**How can I recreate the previous statement in python?**

Comment: For this question it is crucial to include some example data and it would be most optimal if you would also include expected output example.

Comment: Thank you, I will update to include an example

Comment: Note: with example I mean a small dataframe created which we can copy and run ourselves. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Thank you! I've updated per your suggestion

Comment: Thanks to Parfait, who pointed me to a very similar question. There, I found how to use SQL inside python. Might not be the best approach, but I am much more comfortable with SQL, so I used that to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could start by trying this:

```
dfR = df1.copy()
dfR.loc[dfR['TranDate'].between(df2['StartDate'], df2['EndDate']), 'PP'] = df2['PP']
```

Maybe this will work for you.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work for me, but thank you for sharing